# What steps would I need to take to use a kindle fire screen with my RPi?

Tags: display, driver, android

I have a first-generation Kindle Fire and a RPi. The Kindle Fire screen has a LVDS interface. The Kindle Fire runs a modified version of an Android OS.

As background, I have moderate experience in software graphics rendering, but practically no hardware experience.

Here are the steps I'm envisioning I would need to take to use the Kindle screen:

1. Obtain a power source for both components
2. Obtain an adapter for HDMI to LVDS interfaces
3. "Rip" the display drivers from the Kindle operating system (I don't know if this is entirely legal)
4. Apply the graphics drivers to whatever RPi OS I'm using

Am I missing any steps? Would I need to apply the drivers at the kernel level or at an operational level?

Comment: Are you looking to physically take the LCD panel out of your Kindle Fire and connect it to you Pi?  Leaving your KF without any display?  I only ask as I also have a 1st gen KF and dont' see an externally accessible interface other than the micro USB port.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn Yes. Specifically the LCD panel and not the touchscreen interface for now. Here is a [link to a Kindle Fire teardown, the display is visible in step 14.](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Kindle+Fire+Teardown/7099)

Comment: @AwesomeUser I've not had any success in solving this question but I think an answer would prove valuable to the Pi community. I'm hesitant to mark it with a simple "You can't do it." answer.

Comment: @dragonsdoom this link may provide help show what is on the kindle side of things. It's a video so I cannot exactly summarize it on here. http://www.repairsuniverse.com/amazon-kindle-fire-take-apart-repair-guide.html